# Plone 3.3.5 upgrade broken

Tags: plone

I inherited a Plone installation (version 2.5).  It was critical that I upgrade it to 3.3.5.

I set up a test environment and got the old version working.  I set up 3.3.5 and went through the migration steps.  Now whenever I go to a page I get:

```
Macro Expansion failed
exceptions.KeyError: 'header'
```

I've looked in the front_page template (I think that's what it's called) and it has that error listed front and center.  I tried removing the macro tag and it gives me an error about the macro needing to be within the tabs.

From looking at more documentation it looks like Plone has moved away from using macros.  Is there a quick fix to get our site to work as is, or will we have to do some re-writing?

EDITED: From the comments there is a mention of Add-ons needing to be upgraded.  How do I know if I have add-ons? How do I know if they need to be upgraded?  How do I find out how to upgrade them?  The documentation is full of "whats" but very sparse on "Hows".

EDITED: I found the header issue by looking through the old one (there was a header template that was in the old installation but not in the new one, had to figure out how to get it in there), now it's giving me an error about a user-macro="scripts/macros/jsrenderer" and if I remove that there is one for css.  These look like standard entries for plone (since the exact same syntax comes up when I google these...but I can't find the location of the macro anywhere.  Is this something that has changed in version 3?

EDITED: I think I've got it under control now, jumping back and forth between the two installations.  Such a Pain.

Let me know if you need any code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have any addons, they'll also need to upgraded almost certainly.

Comment: You likely have a customized main_template in portal_skins -> custom

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm a Plone virgin.  How do I know if I have any add-ons?  how do I know if they need upgraded?  How do I find out how to upgrade them?

Comment: Custom Addons don't stick out, but you can check in the ZMI, the portal_quickinstaller and check the filesystem for non-plonish products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only give hints for debugging this error. What you can try is:

- Can you find a `define-macro="header"` in the code? If not, that's what your template tries to look up and fails.
- In the ZMI, check the portal_skins -> properties tab. I think most of the views (templates) are mapped as filesystem directory folders. These need to be registered in each skin layer. **The order of each entry** is important, as that's the way macros are looked up. Check if each layer has access to each directory view.*
- Check if a custom product defines yet another 'main_template.pt' which (re-)defines different macros.
- From my experience, a lot of customization happened in page templates. In the traceback you should find, which template the error is happening. Try to look up `use-macro=""` statements which perhaps point to macros which are different or don't exist anymore.

Furthermore, no - page templates with macros are still in use. Good luck!

Comment: Where do I find the Macros?  They're listed as here/header/macros/htmls_header etc...but I don't see that file structure in my filesystem.

Comment: What you find are so called [path expressions](http://chameleon.repoze.org/docs/latest/reference.html#macros-metal). The statement means, use the html_header macro in the nearest header object. **header** can refer to a header.pt for example.